# How to turn showerhead without creating a leak

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak

**Situation:**

- Shower head is positioned on the red line. The water shoots too close to the wall. Even with adjusting the "front" of the shower head, the positioning of the pipe prevents it from being able to shoot dead center in the shower.
  [image]
- I want to turn it ~45 degrees counter clockwise.
- My plan is to unscrew it, add generous thread sealing tape and then position it to the blue line.
  [image]

**Perceived Problem:**

- My plan may fail and I might create a leak.

**Question(s):**

- Is there anything I'm failing to consider or are there other ways to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either do your plan which will work if you wrap the ptfe on tightly in the correct direction (clockwise).

Or just consider turning the shower head assembly clockwise 315 degrees.

Comment: Depending on how tight/leak proof it is now, might be able to go just 45 the other way.  Usually threads have about a turn either way before leaking, if done up tight in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of tape, use thread sealing paste such as [THIS](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RectorSeal-No-5-Pipe-Thread-Sealant-Sealant/3134515?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_142_Pipe-Fittings-_-3134515-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAiAqaWdBhAvEiwAGAQltos6zNiYht0CZYB8Bbbj-ME3np7tQJ3ELwIaJ7e724atBsqoq0VQmxoCy8oQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).
The sealer does as implied and seals the threads even if the arm is not as tight as one expects. ( it still has to be threaded in and made at least pretty snug.)

Comment: The link does not seem to be working. Perhaps specify a product name / number so one could google it.

Comment: The link worked for me. Here's the product name **RectorSeal No. 5 Pipe Thread Sealant**. [This link](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RectorSeal-No-5-Pipe-Thread-Sealant-Sealant/3134515) may work as I stripped lots of cruft from the end of the URL.